# Moving Node with JavaFX DropShadow leaves trail

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, dropshadow

In a game I am working on in JavaFX, I have cards ([`Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html)s) with [`DropShadow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/DropShadow.html)s. The cards can move, and, when they do, the shadow leaves behind a faint trail. I've tried using [`Node#setCache(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setCache-boolean-), which works, but blurs the text in the label.

**Are there any other ways to prevent a `DropShadow` from leaving a trail?**

Here is a MCVE with the result:

```
public class DropShadowTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Label label = new Label("Hello, world!");
        label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY, new CornerRadii(10), Insets.EMPTY)));
        label.setEffect(new DropShadow(3, 0, 1, Color.BLACK));
        label.setMaxSize(100, 100);
        label.setMinSize(100, 100);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(label), 640, 480));
        stage.show();

        label.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            final TranslateTransition anim = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), label);
            anim.setToX(Math.random() * 500 - 250);
            anim.setToY(Math.random() * 300 - 150);
            anim.play();
        });
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Result:
[image: Drop shadow trails]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **Caching**  with the [Cache hints](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/CacheHint.html) , For example before you start animating you set the cache hint to [SPEED](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/CacheHint.html#SPEED)
Once you are done with Animation you switch back to [QUALITY](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/CacheHint.html#QUALITY) , it will re-render your Node (like repaint() in swing)